# Will magnetic field lines change when a magnet gets closer to other magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

As many books tells that the magnetic field can be illustrated by a bunch of field lines, which start from one pole and end up at the other. If I have a strong uniform field with field lines along horizontal direction. What happen if I place a small magnet somewhere away from the field line, will it change the direction of the source field (lines)? I am thinking that some parallel lines should detour so to end up at the south pole of the magnet. But how much will it change the uniform field?

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is basically correct.

When you have two magnets in a Universe, the field lines are different from when you have only one magnet in that Universe. The amount of change depends on the separation and where you are doing the measurement.

The lines are actually how a small compass needle will orient itself at that position in space. Thus there are field lines *everywhere* ... the few that get drawn are just a visualization tool.

IRL there are a lot more than just the two magnets, and there are other forces... if the disturbance caused by the additional magnets are much smaller than the other stuff we can usually neglect it.